# I have some trouble with str_split, it doesn't work correctly with my language

Tags: php, unicode, farsi

I've a piece of code like this:

```
$string="رستوران";
$arr = str_split($string);
var_dump($arr);
echo '<br>';
```

that the result is:

```
array (size=14)
   0 => string '�' (length=1)
   1 => string '�' (length=1)
   2 => string '�' (length=1)
...
```

but I expect to have result like this:

```
array (size=14)
   0 => string 'ر' (length=1)
   1 => string 'س' (length=1)
   2 => string 'ت' (length=1)
...
```

Do you have any suggestions for achieving my expected result?

Comment: Have you ensured that characters are represented by unicode?

Comment: whats that mean?how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use [Multibyte String Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) for manipulating persian string. 
You can use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) for your porpuse.

```
print_r(preg_split('//u', "رستوران ها", null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
Output:
Array
(
    [0] => ر
    [1] => س
    [2] => ت
    [3] => و
    [4] => ر
    [5] => ا
    [6] => ن
    [7] =>  
    [8] => ه
    [9] => ا
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following

```
$arr = str_split_unicode($string);
```

Create a function to handle this new call

```
function str_split_unicode($str, $l = 0) {
    if ($l > 0) {
        $ret = array();
        $len = mb_strlen($str, "UTF-8");
        for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i += $l) {
            $ret[] = mb_substr($str, $i, $l, "UTF-8");
        }
        return $ret;
    }
    return preg_split("//u", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From PHP 7.4 you can use the mb_str_split() function:

```
$string="رستوران";
mb_str_split($string)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not concerned with the `str_split()` function. You have to change the character encoding of the file to one of the Unicode choices (UTF-8 is the best). The characters you are using are not suppported by the ANSI and ASCII encodings.

Comment: im using meta tag <meta charset="utf-8">is it true?

Comment: You must also set the encoding of the file encoding to UTF-8. The meta tag alone does not solve the problem.